# Fork stuck in in headtube

Tags: road-bike

I have tried hitting it with a mallet but it won't move. There are no spacers. Just a stuck fork. What can I do to fix it? Trying to remove the old fork

Comment: Can you post a picture of the headtube? Are all spacers **and** headset cover removed? Can you see the bearing?

Comment: How old is it? With old style threaded forks you need to disassemble the headset bearing before fork comes out.

Comment: Is the top race compression ring still in place?  See the Wikipedia image:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headset_%28bicycle_part%29#/media/File:Br_aheadset.png  If that compression ring is still in place, it's **really** hard to remove the fork - attempts to force or hammer the steer tube downward will just tighten the compression ring.

Answer (score 4):

It is likely that there has been some corrosion of inner bearing races or the steeerer (or both). Happens more often with cartridge bearings.

I don't know any magic way to easily resolve it. You migh need to continue doing more of the same gradually increasing the effort and being careful not to damage the frame.

Start by removing everything that can be removed from the top: the stem, spacers, headset cover, **compression ring (the last one is important!)**. If something does not come off you can cut it off with a dremel (careful around the frame again).

Apply penetrant (WD40 or similar) to the gap between the steerer and bearing and wait (30 minutes is a reasonable time). Rememebr to apply penetrant to the gap at the bottom of the head tube too.

Make sure that the frame is secured: resting on some firm but not abbrasive surface (wood is ideal). It is a common mistake to keep hammering a stuck steerer while the bike is mounted in the workstand - rarely ever works.

Keep tapping while gradually increasing the force. It will come out eventually. If it is well stuck, don't bother with rubber mallet. Proceed to steel hammer and pad the top of the steerer with some wood.

Comment: *compression ring (the last one is important!)*  You might want to bold that one as the fork probably can't be removed with it in place...